# How to register PdfSharp for SQL CLR in SQL Server 2014?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlclr

I have a CLR stored procedure that invokes PdfSharp 1.32.3057.0 to create a PDF from a given query. PdfSharp registers fine on local dev server (Windows 2012 / SQL Server 2014) but not on QA server (Windows 2008 r2 / SQL Server 2014).

Registration of pdfsharp was attempted under SA account which is dbo for 'util' db.

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY [PdfSharp] 
           FROM 'c:\SqlClr\PdfSharp.dll'
WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE
```

> **Warning**: the Microsoft .NET Framework assembly 'system.windows.forms, version=2.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b77a5c561934e089, processorarchitecture=msil.' you are registering is not fully tested in the SQL Server hosted environment and is not supported. In the future, if you upgrade or service this assembly or the .NET Framework, your CLR integration routine may stop working. Please refer SQL Server Books Online for more details.
>
> Msg 6586, Level 16, State 1, Line 118
>   Assembly 'System.Windows.Forms' could not be installed because existing policy would keep it from being used

`is_trustworthy` is set to on for util db.

.NET 4.7.2 and .NET 3.5.1 are both installed on QA server.

How do you register this assembly without error?

Comment: this is not a recoverable error. even if you could somehow suppress or circumvent that limitation, it would probably result in an unstable system or worse. run the pdf generator out-of-process (do not host it in the SQL Server managed runtime)

Answer (score 2):

1) This is a *bad idea*.  You should use an external program, perhaps simply PowerShell through SQL Agent to do this.

2) Here's how to do it anyway.

The assembly you're attempting to load references .NET framework assemblies not on the "blessed list" for SQL Server, which means that they are not tested or supported for running in-proc.  And to use them you have to copy them into your database.

Once you copy .NET Framework assemblies in your database you must update them any time the .NET Framework version on the host changes (including patches and minor version changes), or your database runs on another server (eg failover).  Someone *will* forget to do this and your app will crash.

SQL 2012 and later use .NET Framework 4.  It's no big deal that the app was built against .NET 2; it will run in 4 (probably).  And the .NET Framework 2 assembly references will be silently redirected to the .NET 4 versions.  But this means that you must install the .NET 4 versions from the server into your database.  The complete list you need to get System.Windows.Forms.dll working is:

```
system.windows.forms, version=4.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b77a5c561934e089, processorarchitecture=msil
system.drawing, version=4.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorarchitecture=msil
accessibility, version=4.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorarchitecture=msil
system.runtime.serialization.formatters.soap, version=4.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorarchitecture=msil
```

These assemblies are all located in:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
```

Comment: Understood.  We might be able to convert this to HttpClient making a web api call.  In this scenario pdf is created out of process.  Is System.Net.Http / HttpClient safe to use in SQL CLR 2014?

Comment: System.Net.WebClient and System.Net.HttpWebRequest are both in System.dll, which is on the "blessed list", and can be used in external_access or unsafe assemblies without installing additional .NET Framework assemblies.

Answer (score 1):

1. .NET Framework version 3.5.1 is irrelevant here since you are using SQL Server 2014 which is tied to *only* CLR version 4.0 (and hence .NET Framework versions 4.0 and newer, at least through 4.7.2).
2. Somehow you are pointing to the wrong version of the `System.Windows.Forms` library. The error states `'system.windows.forms, version=2.0.0.0,...` which is for CLR version 2.0, not CLR version 4.0. So you need to place the **System.Windows.Forms.dll** file from .NET 4.x into **c:\SqlClr\** so that it can be automatically loaded when you attempt to load PdfSharp.
3. You need to do *thorough* testing, with multiple concurrent users accessing this SQLCLR object at the exact same time. I have not looked into PdfSharp, but if the reason it is `UNSAFE` is due to using static class variables to cache values for performance, that could easy cause odd, unexpected, unpredictable behavior since AppDomains in SQL Server are shared across all sessions. This means that multiple concurrent users have access to the same static class variables. This can lead to race conditions where one user overwrites a value being used by another user. You would need to attempt loading PdfSharp as `SAFE` or `EXTERNAL_ACCESS` to see what error message is returned, which should indicate at least one reason that this library needs to be marked as `UNSAFE`.

   If static class variables are being used to cache per-execution values, then you should either:

   1. add the "readonly" keyword to the static class variable declaration and recompile. When you compile, if there are places in the code that write to that variable, they will generate errors. You will need to fix each place where that occurs. You could attempt removing the "static" keyword (and obviously not adding "readonly") making it an instance variable, which is safe to use.
   2. not use solution and find something else

For more info on working with SQLCLR in general, please visit: [SQLCLR Info](https://SQLclr.org/)